# How does JNPM affect Http-Requests?

Tags: java, spring, npm

I'm using Java Spring Boot and have a Service, where i make a GET-Request to the Github-API.
This works fine.

Now i want to use JNPM to get infos on npm-packages.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.orienteer.jnpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jnpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

With this dependency, my GET-Requests to the API now give me the error:

```
method GET must not have a request body.
```

I don't use any methods of JNPM, just have the dependency added.

Anyone know why this problem occurs or does anyone know an alternative API to access the NPM registry?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as you have not mentioned your code here, but as per the error, it says: method GET must not have a request body.
while making a get request to the Github API you must have attached a request body to this request, and since it's of GET method, it can not have any body. You should check the docs of the API and also check your code if you are using the API correctly.
Also, check your jnpm library if it's doing something behind the scene like adding a body to your requests.